# SQL Database backup and Google Compute Engine

Tags: sql-server, google-compute-engine

We've recently moved from Rackspace to Google Compute Engine. As regards backing up an instance, daily snapshots work great. However, backing up our MSSQL database and moving the backup files elsewhere is not clear to me. I have no problem setting up a schedule for backing up our databases with MSSQL, but I also need to copy the backups to a secondary cloud storage bucket (so I can restore data if necessary without restoring the entire instance). I don't see where I can set up a schedule for doing that. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Sally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload any file from your GCP VM instance try using `gsutil`; here's how:

- create a bucket (or use existing one - it's up to you
- upload a file: `gsutil cp file_to_upload.name gs://mybackupbucket/backup_dir/`

Here's some useful documentation on that:

- [Uploading a files from VM to a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/tools/powershell/docs/backup#upload_files_to_a_bucket)
- [Listing objects in bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#gsutil) (usefull to get a correct full pathname)

If you have already set-up backing up you DB to a file every day or so then you can for example add another `cron` job to copy the file to a bucket.